# Clone Ubuntu and Windows to new SSD

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, filesystem, ssd

I want to switch to SSD from HDD. I have dual boot on my hp laptop. My C drive in Windows and Ubuntu `/` directories have less size than new SSD.

But the whole HDD is of 1 TB and SSD of 240 GB. I am putting my SSD inside laptop using hard disk candy into the CD/DVD slot. And I'm not planning to use the DVD port for DVD again.

How can I clone both systems (only C drive + Ubuntu `/`) without reinstalling everything if that's possible? I want to use SSD for the operating systems and the old HDD for storage. Noob here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Connect both HDD and SSD to the PC.
- *(optional) Boot Windows installation, install drivers for SSD, shutdown.*
- Boot PC from **live cd/usb** (Ubuntu will be ok).
- Open `gparted`. Resize all partitions to smallest possible size, but leave around 100 mb of free space on each one. And move partitions closer to "left border". Apply this operation.
- Open terminal. Detect which drive is your HDD and which one is SSD (see `cat /proc/partitions`)
- `sudo dd if=HDD_DEVICE bs=1M of=SSD_DEVICE` *- it will take some time*

  (for example: `sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M of=/dev/nvme0n1`)
- `sudo partprobe SSD_DEVICE` (for example: /dev/nvme0n1)
- Probably, you'll need to expand partition table and file systems again, so you can use `gparted` again.
- Shutdown. Remove HDD.
- Try to boot again.

Next:

- If everything looks ok, you can connect HDD, format it, and use as you wish.
- **OR** Change UUIDs of HDD file systems: `tune2fs /dev/sda1 -U random /dev/sda1` (probably the same for `sdb` if you have, etc). **But don't do this with your SSD!**

**This operation is potentially dangerous. Be attentive with device names you're using!**

Comment: I don't want to remove and format my HDD. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you check the updated question?

Comment: @YogiKatba. Okey, I've updated answer

Comment: Can you help me on this https://askubuntu.com/q/1287412/1041505

Comment: @YogiKatba, Sorry, I'm not aware of that script and don't know what is the problem there..