# System is not booting up from SSD after cloning and changing UUID

Tags: boot, grub2, filesystem, ssd, bios

I used [clone-ubuntu.sh script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028605/1041505) to clone my ubuntu system from HDD to SSD. The script also changes UUID of SSD. I have both HDD and SSD connected to my laptop. Now there is a grub entry for SSD but when I try to select (i)ubuntu from the SSD, some lines appears on screen [ok] did this, did thatxxxx. There wasn't any error on that screen. But after all processes are done, my system boots up from old HDD. When I select (ii)ubuntu from HDD that screen with [ok]message never appears.

I have checked my UUID by `ls -lha /dev/disk/by-uuid` command.
sda8 is HDD's ubuntu and sdb3 is SSD's ubuntu

Output

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 280 Oct 26 23:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 160 Oct 26 23:11 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 26 23:11 01D3FE55E8E36BD0 -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 26 23:12 01D3FE5627982000 -> ../../sda9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 26 23:11 36D23E46D23E0B1F -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 26 23:11 527237CA7237B199 -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 26 23:12 92216d18-5365-40c9-a442-9cd2181db22b -> ../../sda8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 26 23:11 B2742F92742F587D -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 26 23:12 B634-4FB6 -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 26 23:11 C8908B8D908B80A4 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 26 23:11 cd8a0366-4362-4ef7-8e82-33f43fe1c240 -> ../../sdb3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 26 23:12 E25086035085DF23 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  11 Oct 26 23:12 F0E6C00FE6BFD3D6 -> ../../sda10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  11 Oct 26 23:12 FE26DCC726DC8257 -> ../../sda11
```

How to boot into SSD's ubuntu? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you reinstall grub and change UUIDs in fstab, so new UUIDs used not old one's on HDD. I typically find it easier to just do a new install & copy /home, data & list of installed apts from backup. Your backup should allow quick reinstall, anyway. When hard drive fails that is the way you have to restore to a new drive. Compare `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"` and `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: 1. The cloned file /etc/fstab is modified with the appropriate UUID for the partition it is on.
2. The cloned file /boot/grub/grub.cfg is modified with the appropriate UUID for successful clone booting.
3. update-grub is run to update Grub with new menu options pointing to the cloned partition. These points are from the scripts I ran. And as per `ls -lha /dev/disk/by-uuid` output. UUIDs are different

Comment: May or may not show something. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/